# ERROR: insert has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql

I have a function getLocationId.  It operates on a table, Location,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Location ( 
     longitude double precision NOT NULL check( -180.0 < longitude AND longitude <= 180.0 ),
     latitude double precision NOT NULL check( -90.0 <= latitude AND latitude <= 90.0 ),
     altitude double precision  default(0), 
     unique(longitude,latitude,altitude),
     loc_id integer  DEFAULT nextval('loc_loc_id_seq'::regclass) 
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getLocationId( lng double precision, lat double precision,alt double precision ) RETURNS integer AS $gli$
DECLARE
        lid integer;
BEGIN
     SELECT loc_id into lid from Location where lng = longitude AND lat = latitude AND alt = altitude;
     if NOT FOUND then
        insert into Location VALUES ( lng , lat , alt ) RETURNING loc_id as lid;
     END IF;
     RETURN lid;
END;
$gli$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run it, I get:

```
select * from getLocationId( -73.993953611111,40.7192777778,10.8);
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "getlocationid" line 11 at SQL statement
```

Can someone help.

Answer (score 2):

I used AS instead of INTO in the insert statement. It needs to be:

```
... RETURNING loc_id INTO lid;
```